# A set which is closed bounded and convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I have a set

$$B=\{x=(x_1,x_2)\in R^2_+ \mid 2\sqrt{x_1}+x_2\le y\}$$

where $y>0$ is any number.

And I want to show that this set B is closed bounded and convex.

————-

**My Solution is as follows:**

First of all, I show this set in figure like that (but I am not sure about correctness, please tell me if it is wrong)
[Figure of the set is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JF7D.jpg) Is that figure true?

**Secondly I need to show that the set $B$ is closed.**

My idea: we know that any set in $R^2_+$ is closed. So, I try to show that the Set $B$ is closed. I guess I need to show that the complement of $B$ in $R^2_+$ is open. I.e. for every $(x_1, x_2)$ not in B $\exists$ r>0 s.t. $B_r(x1, x2) \cap B = \emptyset$.

Thus, let $f(x_1, x_2)=2\sqrt{x_1}+x_2$ $\forall (x1, x2)\in R^2$ is continuous function

So,
$$B=\{x=(x_1,x_2)\in R^2_+ \mid f(x_1, x_2)\le y\}=f^{-1}[(0,y)]$$

So, $f:R^2_+\to R $ is continuous function then the set B is closed.

But I am exactly unsure about this proof. Please correct my solution.

**Thirdly, I need to show that the set is bounded.**

I guess this set is  bounded both below and above. Thus, the set B is bounded.

For that, We say that a set is bounded above if there is a number $y$ (an upper bound so that every element in the set is no more than $y,$ and I could say that the set $B$ is bounded below if there is a number $M$ (which is equal to zero in this example) (a lower bound) so that every element in the set is no less than $M=0.$

But is this proof enough to show boundedness? What you think about this?

**Finally, the set B is convex**

I select two points $G=(x_1’,x_2’)$ and $N=(x_1’’,x_2’’)$ are in the set. Then I have $2\sqrt{x_1‘}+x_2’=2\sqrt{x_1’’}+x_2’’\le y$

So I use the definition

$$a(x_1’,x_2’)+(1-a)(x_1’’,x_2’’)\in B$$

That’s,

$$2[ax_1’+(1-a)x_1’’]^{1/2}+ [ax_2’+(1-a)x_2’’]\le y$$ for all $a\in [0,1]$

But I cannot further prove this is true for all $G$ and $N.$

Please check my answers and if those are wrong, please correct and improve them.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: some inequality is mistaken, the set with the inequality $\ge y$ is convex, because the function $x\mapsto y - 2 \sqrt{x}$ is convex.

Comment: $B=f^{-1}([0,y])$ (and not $f^{-1}(\{y\})$).

Comment: I am really confusing while proving. Please correct them. Thanks a lot. @orangeskid

Comment: (1). Re : Closed: It's good.  Perhaps it may be better style to say that  $f^{-1}[0,y]$ is closed in the space $\Bbb R^2_+.$ Note the correct notation . If $A$ is a set just write $f^{-1}A$  for $\{p:f(p)\in A\}.$ And you have a typo (missing subscript $+$) in the def'n of $f.$... (2)Re: Bounded: You  can let $z=\max (0,y)$ and observe that $ B\subset (0, z^2/2]\times (0,z]$.

Answer (score 1):

The set is bounded because
0 <= $x_1$ <= $y^2$, 0 <= $x_2$ <= y.

The figure indicates it is not convex.
Consider the line connecting the $x_1$ and $x_2$ intercepts.

When showing the set is closed, the equation for B
ending with [{y}] is wrong.  It should be [[0,y]].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please show why not to be convex more mathematically.

Comment: To the proposer: Consider the case $y=2.$ There is a  point $p\in B$ that is arbitrarily close to $(0,2)$ and a point $q\in  B$ arbitrarily  close to $(1,0).$ But $(p+q)/2$ is arbitrarily close to $(1/2,1)\not \in B,$ and $B$ is closed. The set $B$ is part of the "outside" of a parabola when $y>0$.